Dynamic XPATH loop exiting
So there is a button whoes XPATH changes based on the time, I found the pattern and devised a method to click the button no matter the time.
x=1
while x < 10:
 try:
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{x}]/td[5]/a').click()
  print(f"Join button successfully clicked on attempt {x}")
  time.sleep(3)
  break


 except NoSuchElementException as e:
  print(f"Could not find the Join Button. Error: {e}, retrying... Attempt number: ", x)
  driver.refresh()
  x+=1
  time.sleep(3)
if x == 11:
  driver.quit()
  print("ERROR 93: Join button not found")
  sys.exit(93)
#END OF CODE FOR JOIN BUTTON
#####################################################

The problem with my code is that once it finds the button, it clicks it, but it doesnt break and continues to check for every number after it, I dont know how to fix it, also even after x reaching 10 it doesnt stop and continues forever.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

There are issues with your code, and your question. First, your XPATH is ridiculously fragile. Second, you're not using Waits. Third, you're not including a minimal, reproducible example in your question. Very difficult, if not impossible to help you given these issues. See this guide, and edit your question accordingly.
